# Win32 Mouse and Keyboard combination

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, mouse

I need to combine mouse and keyboard events in Win32, like `Click`+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or `Click`+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

For example (pseudo code):

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

       if (Shift)
            //click+Shift
       if (Shift && Ctrl)
            //click+Shift+Ctrl
       if (Shift && Alt)
            //click+Shift+Alt
break;
```

I know all necessary parameters from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx).

But I don't know how to combine them properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that this is inside your winproc:

```
if(wParam & MK_SHIFT)
{
   if (wParam & MK_CONTROL && wParam & MK_SHIFT)
   {
     //click+Shift+Ctrl
   }
   else if(wParam & MK_SHIFT && HIBYTE(GetKeyState(VK_MENU)) & 0x80)
   {
        //alt+shift
   }
   else
   {
      //just shift
   }
}
```

Shift and click and alt is a bit trickier you have to use a different way

Why like that? You will notice from [WM_LBUTTONDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page that for each signal sent you have parameters given. One of them is the wparam. It can have different values depending on whether some special keys are pressed or not

And since the wparam of the WM_LBUTTONDOWN signal does not contain information about the alt button you would have to utilize the [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which returns a high order bit value of 1 if the key is down and anything else if it's not.

Comment: it works with "wParam & MK_SHIFT" not "wParam == MK_SHIFT", whats wrong?

Comment: Hehe correct observation. I made a big typo in my answer. Wparam contains bitflags and so you have to check with logical AND '&'.
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hm ... from the code you posted in your question, I thought that this was your intended functionality. Well .. this is just a simple problem of program flow. I will fix my answer to reflect it .

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GetKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the state of the modifier keys at the time the current message was generated. So:

```
if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0 && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) {
    // click+shift+ctrl
} else if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) < 0) {
    // click+shift
}
```

and so on. Note that you will want to check for the multi-key combinations *before* a single shift key, otherwise the single shift test will succeed even if some other modifier key is down.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but your wndproc should have several parameters, one of them being the wParam.  The wParam will have the virtual key codes in question.  depending on how in depth you want to get you may want to have an inner switch, like so:

```
switch (wParam)
{
   case MK_CONTROL:
   {
        // handle mouse and ctrl key down
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my current project we're setting flags in the WM_KEYDOWN section of our wndproc:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
{
switch(wParam)
    {
    case VK_CONTROL:
        {
            isHoldingCtrl = true;
        }
        break;
    case VK_SHIFT:
        {
            isHoldingShift = true;
        }
        break;
    case VK_NUMPAD1:
        }
            numPad = 1;
        }
        break;
    }
}
break;
```

This allows us to use any key as a modifier (eg, numpad keys), which we need to do in this project. We then define "normal" key events in WM_KEYUP.

I'm not claiming this is necessarily the best solution for your particular problem, but it is another option, and is an excellent fit for certain sets of needs.